# Using the chain rule to finding the second order partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> $z=f(x,y)$ where $x=r\cos\theta $ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Find $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $ \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$

I'm having big troubles with using chain rule, in particularly the second derivative. Spent 2 hours on this already. What I have...

$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial θ}\frac{\partial θ}{\partial x}$. So I'm guessing that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial θ}$ are unkown? And I will need to use them to differentiate again. Any help is really welcome. This is simply only part of a bigger question.

Full Problem:
[image]

Comment: The problem is incomplete. What is $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$??

Comment: The answer is a collection of functions (of r)

Comment: [See this](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/275-the-laplacian-in-polar-coordinates/)

Comment: And you may want to get these two accounts merged by [contacting SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact).